Convert Swift Data to String in LLDB
I am debugging a Swift application using LLDB (note: this application does not have debug symbols).
I want to display the Swift Data object pointed to by the x1 register as a String.
I tried the following code, but none of them worked and an error was displayed instead of showing the String.
How can I display the Data object at the address pointed to by the x1 register as a String?
(lldb) po String(data: $x1, encoding: .utf8)
error: <user expression 9>:1:12: expected ')'
String(data: $x1, encoding: .utf8)
           ^
<user expression 9>:1:7: to match this '('
String(data: $x1, encoding: .utf8)

(lldb) expr -l Swift -- var myData = Data(bytes: $x1, count: 16)
error: <EXPR>:3:26: error: cannot find '$x1' in scope
var myData = Data(bytes: $x1, count: 16)


Swift doesn't have a natural representation for register data in its type system, so the swift expression parser doesn't support the register argument variables.  You can paste the value of the register (using register read $x1) into the expression as a literal as a workaround.

You should print out the value in the register first
(lldb) register read x1
      x1 = 0x0123456789abcdef

Then use that value to create a pointer:
String(
    decoding:  Data(
        bytes: UnsafeRawPointer(bitPattern: 0x0123456789abcdef)!, 
        count: 8 // or however many bytes you want
    ), 
    as: UTF8.self
)

// in one line
po String(decoding: Data(bytes: .init(bitPattern: 0x0123456789abcdef)!, count: 8), as: UTF8.self)


If you expect the bytes to be a C string (null-terminated), use decodeCString:
po String.decodeCString(.init(bitPattern: 0x0123456789abcdef), as: UTF8.self)

